# how to set variable value from the server response extjs 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

forum member I am having one problem in setting the value of my view from the server response I am receiving

I am using the MVC architechture of the extjs 4. My store is loaded perfectly and my **taskstore** is defined as below

```
Ext.define('gantt.store.taskStore', {
    extend: 'Gnt.data.TaskStore',
    model: 'gantt.model.ResourceTask',
    storeId: 'taskStore',
    autoLoad : true,
    autoSync : true,
    proxy       : {
        type : 'ajax',
        api: {
            read:       'task/GetTask.action',
            create:     'task/CreateTask.action',
            destroy:    'task/DeleteTask.action',
            update:     'task/UpdateTask.action'
        },
        writer : new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
            //type : 'json',
            root : 'taskdata',
            encode : true,
            writeAllFields : true
        }),
        reader : new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            totalPropery: 'total',
            successProperty : 'success',
            idProperty : 'id',
            type : 'json',
            root: function (o) {
                if (o.taskdata) {
                    return o.taskdata;
                } else {
                    return o.children;
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

but what I want to do is that as soon as the store loaded I want to assign the server response data to one of the variable in my javascript.

I tried to add the value from the beforeload function of view, but not able to do so.

**my view code is given as below**

```
var result = Ext.JSON.decode('{"calendardata": [{"startdate": 1330281000000,"enddate": 1330284600000,"id": 3,"title": "mon"}],"total": 1,"success": true}');

//var start   = new Date(2012, 2, 26),
//end     = Sch.util.Date.add(start, Sch.util.Date.MONTH, 30);

var start_d = new Date(result.calendardata[0].startdate);
var end_d = new Date(result.calendardata[0].enddate);

var start = new Date(start_d.getFullYear(), start_d.getMonth(), start_d.getDate());
end = Sch.util.Date.add(start, Sch.util.Date.MONTH, 30);

console.log("YEAR ::"+start.getFullYear()+"MONTH ::"+start.getMonth()+"DAY ::"+start.getDate());
console.log("YEAR ::"+end.getFullYear()+"MONTH ::"+end.getMonth()+"DAY ::"+end.getDate());

//create the downloadframe at the init of your app
this.downloadFrame = Ext.getBody().createChild({
                tag: 'iframe'
                    , cls: 'x-hidden'
                    , id: 'iframe'
                    , name: 'iframe'
            });
//create the downloadform at the init of your app

            this.downloadForm = Ext.getBody().createChild({
                tag: 'form'
                    , cls: 'x-hidden'
                    , id: 'form'
                    , target: 'iframe'
            });

            var printableMilestoneTpl = new Gnt.template.Milestone({
                prefix : 'foo',
                printable : true,
                imgSrc : 'resources/images/milestone.png'
            });

            var params = new Object();
Ext.define('gantt.view.projectmgt.projectGanttpanel', {
    extend: "Gnt.panel.Gantt",
    id: 'projectganttpanel',
    alias: 'widget.projectganttpanel',
    requires: [
                'Gnt.plugin.TaskContextMenu',
                'Gnt.column.StartDate',
                'Gnt.column.EndDate',
                'Gnt.column.Duration',
                'Gnt.column.PercentDone',
                'Gnt.column.ResourceAssignment',
                'Sch.plugin.TreeCellEditing',
                'Sch.plugin.Pan',
                'gantt.store.taskStore',
                'gantt.store.dependencyStore'
              ],           
              leftLabelField: 'Name',
              loadMask: true,
              //width: '100%',
            //  height: '98%',      
              startDate: start,
              endDate: end,
              multiSelect: true,
              cascadeChanges: true,
              viewPreset: 'weekAndDayLetter',
              recalculateParents: false,
              showTodayLine               : true,
              showBaseline                : true,


              initComponent: function() {
                var me = this;  
                me.on({
                    scope: me,
                    beforeload: function(store,records,options) {
                        console.log('BEFORE LOAD YAAR panel'+records.params);

                          if(records.params['id'] != null)
                          {
                              return true;

                          }
                          else
                          {
                              return false;
                          }
                    }           
                });


                TaskPriority = {
                        Low : 0,
                        Normal : 1,
                        High : 2
                    };
                    var taskStore = Ext.create('gantt.store.taskStore');
                    var dependencyStore = Ext.create('gantt.store.dependencyStore');

                     Ext.apply(me, {
                         taskStore: taskStore,
                         dependencyStore: dependencyStore,

                         // Add some extra functionality
                        plugins : [
                            Ext.create("Gnt.plugin.TaskContextMenu"), 
                            Ext.create('Sch.plugin.TreeCellEditing', { 
                                clicksToEdit: 1
                            }),
                           Ext.create('Gnt.plugin.Printable', {
                                printRenderer : function(task, tplData) {
                                if (task.isMilestone()) {
                                    return;
                                } else if (task.isLeaf()) {
                                    var availableWidth = tplData.width - 4,
                                        progressWidth = Math.floor(availableWidth*task.get('PercentDone')/100);

                                    return {
                                        // Style borders to act as background/progressbar
                                        progressBarStyle : Ext.String.format('width:{2}px;border-left:{0}px solid #7971E2;border-right:{1}px solid #E5ECF5;', progressWidth, availableWidth - progressWidth, availableWidth)
                                    };
                                } else {
                                    var availableWidth = tplData.width - 2,
                                        progressWidth = Math.floor(availableWidth*task.get('PercentDone')/100);

                                    return {
                                        // Style borders to act as background/progressbar
                                        progressBarStyle : Ext.String.format('width:{2}px;border-left:{0}px solid #FFF3A5;border-right:{1}px solid #FFBC00;', progressWidth, availableWidth - progressWidth, availableWidth)
                                    };
                                }
                            },
                            beforePrint : function(sched) {
                                var v = sched.getSchedulingView();
                                this.oldRenderer = v.eventRenderer;
                                this.oldMilestoneTemplate = v.milestoneTemplate;
                                v.milestoneTemplate = printableMilestoneTpl;
                                v.eventRenderer = this.printRenderer;
                            },

                            afterPrint : function(sched) {
                                var v = sched.getSchedulingView();
                                v.eventRenderer = this.oldRenderer;
                                v.milestoneTemplate = this.oldMilestoneTemplate;
                            }
                        })
                        ],
                             eventRenderer: function (task) {
                                 var prioCls;
                                 switch (task.get('Priority')) {
                                     case TaskPriority.Low:
                                         prioCls = 'sch-gantt-prio-low';
                                         break;

                                     case TaskPriority.Normal:
                                         prioCls = 'sch-gantt-prio-normal';
                                         break;

                                     case TaskPriority.High:
                                         prioCls = 'sch-gantt-prio-high';
                                         break;
                                 }

                                 return {
                                     cls: prioCls
                                 };
                             },

                             // Setup your static columns
                             columns: [
                                {
                                    xtype : 'treecolumn',
                                    header: 'Tasks',
                                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                                    width: 150,
                                    field: new Ext.form.TextField()
                                },
                                new Gnt.column.StartDate(),
                                new Gnt.column.Duration(),
                                new Gnt.column.PercentDone(),
                                {
                                    header: 'Priority',
                                    width: 50,
                                    dataIndex: 'Priority',
                                    renderer: function (v, m, r) {
                                        switch (v) {
                                            case TaskPriority.Low:
                                                return 'Low';

                                            case TaskPriority.Normal:
                                                return 'Normal';

                                            case TaskPriority.High:
                                                return 'High';
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                     xtype       : 'booleancolumn',
                                     width       : 50,

                                     header      : 'Manual',

                                     dataIndex   : 'ManuallyScheduled',

                                     field       : { 
                                         xtype   : 'combo',
                                         store   : [ 'true', 'false' ]
                                     }
                                }
                             ],
                            tooltipTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                                 '<h4 class="tipHeader">{Name}</h4>',
                                 '<table class="taskTip">',
                                 '<tr><td>Start:</td> <td align="right">{[Ext.Date.format(values.StartDate, "y-m-d")]}</td></tr>',
                                 '<tr><td>End:</td> <td align="right">{[Ext.Date.format(Ext.Date.add(values.EndDate, Ext.Date.MILLI, -1), "y-m-d")]}</td></tr>',
                                 '<tr><td>Progress:</td><td align="right">{PercentDone}%</td></tr>',
                                 '</table>'
                         ).compile()                             

                     });

                        me.callParent(arguments);

        }     
});
```

the reason I am not able to set the value of variable I used to set it using static data. To set the static data I am using the below code

```
var result = Ext.JSON.decode('{"calendardata": [{"startdate": 1330281000000,"enddate": 1330284600000,"id": 3,"title": "mon"}],"total": 1,"success": true}');

var start_d = new Date(result.calendardata[0].startdate);
var end_d = new Date(result.calendardata[0].enddate);

var start = new Date(start_d.getFullYear(), start_d.getMonth(), start_d.getDate());
end = Sch.util.Date.add(start, Sch.util.Date.MONTH, 30);
```

but instead of this static data I want to set the start and end value as soon as the store loads and server response is received.

please suggest me some solution I can apply here.

I am receiving the jsondata as

```
{
    "taskdata": [{
        "startdate": 1330281000000,
        "enddate": 1330284600000,       
        "id": 3,
        "title": "mon"
    }],
    "total": 1,
    "success": true
}
```

I am using extjs 4 with MVC architecture and JAVA as my server side technology.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is kind of badly formulated. You have too much code and not really clear what are you trying to ask. In a future try to isolate a particular problem you're dealing with if you want to get quick and proper answer.

Second, load operation is asynchronous. You just specified store as 'autoLoad', but I don't see anywhere where you subscribe to its load event. Most likely your problem is trying to get something of the store while it's not yet loaded. Try to set `autoLoad: false`, load store manually and subscribe to its 'load' event to populate your view.

Comment: Just for your understanding I had provided you the code. But don't know why you are saying it is badly formulated. And **also you haven't read my question carefully I want to assign the value received from the store to some variable in my view**. But don't know why are you focusing on some another things. I had provide all the code which is currently working not just the rough code and asking for you help. So please don't divert anywhere else and if you   had any idea regarding my problem then please suggest me.

Comment: I put some suggestions in my answer originally. Did you try them?

Comment: I had tried your suggestion. But I want something like as soon as I received the store response I can assign the received data to variable in my view **var result = Ext.JSON.decode('');** when decode contains the response string.

Comment: You still need to subscribe to the store 'load' event. You can do this in store definition I suppose, but that doesn't change anything. You can't assume that store is already loaded when you are rendering your view.